# Wrong available memory with LXC virtualization

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtual-machine, lxc, ubuntu-16.04

I have virtualized operation system using LXC virtualization. That system reports wrong available memory - it is always same as free memory. By experiments I was able to use more memory than amount of reported available memory so I am sure that available memory is wrongly calculated.

Is it possible to fix this problem? I can not change type of virtualization but it is possible for me to change the configuration.

Host computer: Ubuntu 16.04

Guest computer: Ubuntu 16.04 `4.4.0-22-generic #39-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 5 16:53:32 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

```
cat /proc/meminfo 
MemTotal:        2048448 kB
MemFree:         1382508 kB
MemAvailable:    1382508 kB
Buffers:               0 kB
Cached:           418400 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:           971248 kB
Inactive:         687476 kB
Active(anon):     333484 kB
Inactive(anon):   414684 kB
Active(file):     637764 kB
Inactive(file):   272792 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:       2095100 kB
SwapFree:        2017328 kB
Dirty:               168 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:        528524 kB
Mapped:           251992 kB
Shmem:            210652 kB
Slab:               0 kB
SReclaimable:     165148 kB
SUnreclaim:        24392 kB
KernelStack:        5456 kB
PageTables:        18800 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:     3119324 kB
Committed_AS:    2141108 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:           0 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:     69632 kB
CmaTotal:              0 kB
CmaFree:               0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:      210936 kB
DirectMap2M:     1886208 kB
```

Answer (score 0):

Sadly not specific reason was found. Updating packages of lxc, lxd and restarting server fixed the problem. I hope that permanently.